# If $A \subseteq B$, show that $A^\prime \subseteq B^\prime$ where $A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ are the accumulation points of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> If $A \subseteq B$, show that $A^\prime \subseteq B^\prime$ where $A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ are the accumulation points of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

**My attempt:**

Suppose $x \in A^\prime \implies B^\prime(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every $r>0$.

Thus $B^\prime (x,r) \subseteq A$.

But we have that $A \subseteq B$ hence $B^\prime (x,r) \subseteq A \subseteq B$. Thus if $x \in B^\prime (x,r) \implies x \in B$ and so we have $B^\prime (x,r) \cap B \neq \emptyset \implies x \in B^\prime$.

Thus proving that $A^\prime \subseteq B^\prime$

Is this attempt correct? If not, can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I can go about fixing and improving the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in A'$ then there exists a sequence $x_{n}$ in A converging to x, but since $A \subset B$ , then the sequence $x_{n}$ is in B, and converges to x. Hence x is an accumulation point of "B", hnece $A' \subset B'$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily true that $B'(x,r)\subseteq A$. What is true: $B'(x,r)\cap A\subseteq A$. So it's an easy fix.